# How to add the red color Google+ login button for android? (Not the white color one)

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm following https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in to add the google plus login to my android app.

This documentation recommends following way to add the red color Google plus login button.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
```

But the problem is setScopes method is deprecated now. (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton)

```
setScopes(Scope[] scopes)
This method was deprecated. Setting scopes will no longer impact the branding.
```

I tried following method also.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this , this)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

But the red color Google+ button not appearing. How to add following button then?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read [Plus API Deprecation Notes](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/api-deprecation), you will find the following note at the end:

> With the deprecation of the Google+ People API, we also changed our
>   [branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines). All sign-in buttons should be branded as "Google
>   Sign In" with either **blue** or **white** backgrounds.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Google+  Red color button available only **play-services-8.1.0**  After that google updated Button color and style . so create Customize button using following steps

[Customize your sign-in button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/custom-button)

Comment: The link you provided don't explain how to create the red colour google plus sign in button. Can you please tell me how to do that?